# Postman Xero API - no organisational data?

Tags: postman, xero-api, xero

I work for a lending company and I am trying to use the Xero API to pull data out of our customers balance sheets.

I am following the postman api instructions posted by Xero, but during the authentication stage when I press 'get new token', I can't allow access to anything as I do not have any organisational setup below.

However, I am a collaborator / standard access to the app where I pull the client ID and secret from.

If I could get some pointers on what my next steps should be that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you press the 'GET new access token' button, the person who logs in needs to have standard or advisor role in the Xero organisation you are trying to connect to. It sounds like you don't have the required access and so you would need to ask someone else to generate the token who does have the relevant access.